# Best practice for base class processing data set in class' constructor (Python)

Tags: python

I need to do some post-processing on initiated variables in the base class.

Here's a very simple example of what I currently do:

```
class B(A):
   def __init__(self):
      super(B,self).__init__()

      self.list = ["Black", "Orange", "White"]

      super(B,self).post_init()

class A():
   def __init__(self):
      self.list = []

   def post_init(self):
      self.processed_list = list(map(some_function, self.list))
```

Is there a more respected way of doing this?

Thanks.

Comment: No need to call super. Just `self.post_init()` is fine.

Comment: Good point, thanks Daniel.